# cProfile has no method runcall

Tags: python, python-2.7, cprofile

I'm trying to use cProfile to profile some python code. I believe I need to use `cProfile.runcall()`, not `cProfile.run()`, since the method I want to run is of the form `self.funct()` rather than simply `funct()`.

When I try to use `cProfile.runcall`, detailed [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile), I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'runcall'`

Has the runcall method been removed from cProfile? If so, is there an alternate method to use of the form `cProfile.runcall(self.funct,*args)`?

Minimum (not) working example:

```
import cProfile

def funct(a):
    print a

cProfile.runcall(funct,"Hello")
```

Comment: I recently discovered (the hard way) that the `cProfile` module isn't interchangeable with the `profile` module. In other words the first statement in the Python 2,7 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) for them, that "Both the `profile` and `cProfile` modules provide the following functions: ...", is patently wrong—and the differences aren'y described anywhere (that I could locate).

Comment: @martineau I wondered about this, too, but I find it also doesn't work with `profile`.

Comment: PProteus: Oh, in this case it's your mistake. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48671032/355230) I just posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, the problem is because `runcall()` is a method of a `Profile` *class* instance, not a module-level function (which is how your code is trying to use it). You need to construct an instance of one first, as shown in code snippet in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#profile.Profile).

This seems to work (in Python 2.7.14):

```
import cProfile

def funct(a):
    print a

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
pr.runcall(funct, "Hello")
```